# Reference request - foliated space consisting of algebraic varieties

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, reference-request

I am looking for some information about a notion which I am sure exists in math, but I just don't know where. I think I'll start with an example, and then proceed to the question itself.

Consider the parametric family of polynomials in two real variables:
$$P_a(x,y)=y-ax^3$$
and denote
$$Z_a=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:P_a(x,y)=0\}$$
$Z_a$ is a (very simple) algebraic variety for all $a$. Now consider the set
$$Z:=\bigcup_{a\in[1,2]}Z_a$$
This set looks something like this:

[image]

It's not an algebraic variety, but it is in a sense foliated by algebraic varieties. Another example would be $P_a(x,y)=x^2+y^2-a$. In this case, $Z$ will be an annulus.

Is there a standard name for objects of this type? And where can I read some basic properties of those? I am especially interested in properties of the "singular" points which arise due to taking the union. In the first example above, the set $Z$ looks "mostly" like a 2-dimensional manifold with boundary, except for the origin, which is "singular" in some sense. It is not a singular point for any of the curves in the union, but due to taking the union it becomes special. Is there a name for these points? In the annulus example, there are no such points.

This question is not very well posed, since it is just based on examples, and I am not sure what precisely I am looking for. But this also means that I'm fine with many different types of answers and suggestions. I'm not an algebraic geometry person, so perhaps this is very basic. Either way, thanks a lot for your help!